# How to use COUNT() with MYSQLi and Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli

I need to count the number of persons with the same status from a table for a specific user.. I want to use prepared statements so I did something like this (not working):

```
$sql = 'SELECT status, COUNT(personID) FROM user_persons GROUP BY status WHERE userID = ?';

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $userID);
    $stmt->bind_result($status, $count);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[$status] = $count;
    }
}
```

I want to get an array like this:

```
$data[favorite] = 126
$data[otherstatus] = 345
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the GROUP BY should be after the WHERE clause.

```
$sql = 'SELECT status, COUNT(personID) FROM user_persons WHERE userID = ? GROUP BY status'
```

Are you getting any other errors? Or was it just not doing what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Put an alias to it, e.g:

`$sql = 'SELECT status, COUNT(personID) AS count_p FROM user_persons WHERE userID = ? GROUP BY status';`

...then pick it up using:

fetch_object:

`$row->count_p`

fetch_assoc:

`$row['count_p']`